# why does std::numeric_limits<float>::min() differ in behavior when streamed to output with different functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, format-specifiers, numeric-limits

I got a weird behaviour with

```
 std::numeric_limits<float>::min()
```

when I call std::cout I get an output value of 1.17549e-38

in contrast when I use

```
printf("%f", std::numeric_limits<float>::min());
```

I get a value of 0.000000.

note that when I evaluate (`std::numeric_limits<float>::min() ==  std::numeric_limits<float>::min()`) I get `true` (which is intuitive and logical)

**so, can any one explain to me this difference in output?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cppreference for numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

`std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` returns `FLT_MIN`.

The returned value (which is not `0` in reality) displayed using `%f` is actually formatted to fixed number of decimal places. The `'%f'` format prints 6 decimal places in fixed format.

You can use :

```
%e=gives the scientific notation
%g=handles large floating numbers
```

Comment: any suggestion to fix this output with printf?

Comment: Use `%g` or `%e` instead.